# Tracking events from Rails Model with Mixpanel and MengPaneel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mixpanel

I have a Rails project using Mixpanel and MengPaneel and I want to track an event directly from a model. Is this possible?

I've set everything up using the [MengPaneel guide](https://github.com/DouweM/mengpaneel#so-how) and can successfully track events from my controllers.

I have a case where it seems to make more sense to track an event from the model directly, but can't figure out what my next steps are to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use MixPanel's gem instead? here is how to do it:

https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ruby#sending-events

Just create a new initializer (under /config/initializers folder) with this:

`tracker = Mixpanel::Tracker.new(PROJECT_TOKEN)`

And you can call it from the models (or controllers):

`tracker.track(user_id, 'Sent Message')`

Comment: I think you should declare a global var using the $ like: `$tracker = Mixpanel:: ...` and then use `$tracker.track(user_id, 'Action name')` in your controllers/models